# Reading 4-byte IEEE float in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, floating-point, ieee

I'm trying to read a binary file which contains numbers encoded in 4-byte IEEE float. I'm doing this using the .NET `BinaryReader`, but am unsure how to correctly read the data. I'm certainly sure that the `ReadSingle()` method is not giving me the value I'm looking for.

Does anyone know how to do this in .NET?

Comment: Given = ?, Expected = ?, What Greg got = ?

Comment: `ReadSingle` is using IEEE floats. If you're not getting the correct result, you may want to make sure your input data is correctly formatted, and double check if your input data is little-endian vs big-endian. Perhaps flipping the bytes will help you get the right value.

Comment: IEEE-754 is universal.  You certainly *do* use BinaryReader.ReadSingle() to read a float from a binary file.  Getting the file offset wrong is *very* common mishap, you'll read junk.

Comment: Hi, it's not the offset, I think it's just that the magnititude was throwing me. It's a SEGY file and there are a variety of supported formats used, and it's just this particular format I had not yet encountered, however based on comments here I think it is reading correctly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If  the [`BitConverter.ToSingle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.tosingle.aspx)  method isn't working for you, you may need to look into 
[`Array.Reverse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d3877932.aspx) to change the order of your bytes.

You really didn't provide any code in your question (which is **strongly** suggested),
but I'm guessing its like:

```
byte[]  myData = new byte[4];
myBinReader.Read(myData, 0, 4); // Get 4-bytes from the stream.

Array.Reverse(myData);  // Deal with Endian issue?
Single myvalue = BitConverter.ToSingle(myData, 4);
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help. My code was basically just bR.ReadSingle(), and I had also tried bR.ReadBytes(4), and then using the BitConverter. It seems like this is the best option. I was thrown by the magnitude of the data (tiny), and so now that I think it is being read correctly I am scaling the data after reading so that I can have it the way I want (this is seismic data which I will ultimately output as am image). Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`BitConverter.ToSingle` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.tosingle.aspx)

Comment: If `ReadSingle()` is giving the wrong value, I don't see why this would give a different value.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through your input (or read your stream) and make use of BitConverter

```
float value = BitConverter.ToSingle( bytes, index );
```